# can't add objects to NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.3

I'm a newbie working on an RPN calculator, and I'm trying to set up an array of two-member arrays to store string/value pairs so that I can use them later to show the complete sequence of digits/operators pressed to get to wherever the user is now.  The thing is, whatever I've gotten wrong means the arrays won't populate.  Any thoughts about how to fix this?

Here's my code (`oneStringValuePair` and `arrayOfStringValuePairs` are NSMutableArrays declared in .h as `(nonatomic, strong)` and synthesized in .m):

```
NSLog(@"result is float: %f",result);

self.formattedNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"( %@%@%@ )",firstNumber,operation,secondNumber];

NSLog(@"String is %@",self.formattedNumber);

NSMutableArray *pair = self.oneStringValuePair;
NSMutableArray *array = self.arrayOfStringValuePairs;

pair = [pair init];
array = [array init];

if(pair==nil)
{
    NSLog(@"pair is nil.");
}

if (array==nil)
{
    NSLog(@"array is nil.");
}

[pair addObject:self.formattedNumber];

NSLog(@"first array element description: %@", [[pair lastObject] description]);
[pair addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:result]];

NSLog(@"second array element description: %@",[[pair lastObject] description]);
NSLog(@"pair count: %@",self.oneStringValuePair.count);

if (self.arrayOfStringValuePairs)
{
    [array addObject:pair];
}

NSLog(@"count of pairs:  %@",array.count);
```

Here's the NSLog for `5 3 + 6 /` :

```
2012-08-04 08:02:54.550 Calculator[83891:f803] result is float: 8.000000
2012-08-04 08:02:54.552 Calculator[83891:f803] String is ( 3+5 )
2012-08-04 08:02:54.552 Calculator[83891:f803] pair is nil.
2012-08-04 08:02:54.553 Calculator[83891:f803] array is nil.
2012-08-04 08:02:54.554 Calculator[83891:f803] first array element description: (null)
2012-08-04 08:02:54.555 Calculator[83891:f803] second array element description: (null)
2012-08-04 08:02:54.555 Calculator[83891:f803] pair count: (null)
2012-08-04 08:02:54.556 Calculator[83891:f803] count of pairs:  (null)
2012-08-04 08:02:55.987 Calculator[83891:f803] result is float: 0.750000
2012-08-04 08:02:55.988 Calculator[83891:f803] String is ( 6/8 )
2012-08-04 08:02:55.989 Calculator[83891:f803] pair is nil.
2012-08-04 08:02:55.990 Calculator[83891:f803] array is nil.
2012-08-04 08:02:55.991 Calculator[83891:f803] first array element description: (null)
2012-08-04 08:02:55.992 Calculator[83891:f803] second array element description: (null)
2012-08-04 08:02:55.993 Calculator[83891:f803] pair count: (null)
2012-08-04 08:02:55.994 Calculator[83891:f803] count of pairs:  (null)
```

Comment: print the count of the array like this NSLog(@"%ld",[yourArray count]);

Comment: **Never** use `-init` without `+alloc`.

Comment: Aravindhanarvi, thanks--that helped.  Adam, thanks for the reminder.  I now have this image of my forefathers' ghosts coming to torture me nightly if I ever use `-init` without `-alloc` again....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are few problems in your code

```
NSLog(@"result is float: %f",result);

self.formattedNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"( %@%@%@ )",firstNumber,operation,secondNumber];

NSLog(@"String is %@",self.formattedNumber);

// ***** add 
if (self.oneStringValuePair == nil)
{
    self.oneStringValuePair = [NSMutableArray array];
}

if (self.arrayOfStringValuePairs == nil)
{
    self.arrayOfStringValuePairs = [NSMutableArray array];
}

// *****
NSMutableArray *pair = self.oneStringValuePair;
NSMutableArray *array = self.arrayOfStringValuePairs;

//pair = [pair init];   // `init` is used to initialize object
//array = [array init]; // but not allocate object, if array is nil, [array init] will return nil

if (pair==nil)
{
    NSLog(@"pair is nil.");
}

if (array==nil)
{
    NSLog(@"array is nil.");
}

[pair addObject:self.formattedNumber];
NSLog(@"first array element description: %@", [[pair lastObject] description]);

[pair addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:result]];
NSLog(@"second array element description: %@",[[pair lastObject] description]);

// the line below will crash if self.oneStringValuePair is not nil
//NSLog(@"pair count: %@",self.oneStringValuePair.count);
NSLog(@"pair count: %d",self.oneStringValuePair.count);

if (self.arrayOfStringValuePairs)
{
    [array addObject:pair];
}

// the line below will crash if array is not nil
//NSLog(@"count of pairs:  %@",array.count);
NSLog(@"count of pairs:  %d",array);
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  These were all really helpful.  Allocating/initializing is still confusing to me when there are properties involved....

Answer (score 1):

Have you initialized the NSMutableArray like below ?

```
NSMutableArray *pair = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Answer (score 1):

What does this do ?

```
NSMutableArray *pair = self.oneStringValuePair;
NSMutableArray *array = self.arrayOfStringValuePairs;
pair = [pair init];
array = [array init];
```

Can you print and check whether `self.oneStringValuePair` & `self.arrayOfStringValuePairs` is nil or not. if it is nil, allocate those two objects like this.

```
self.oneStringValuePair = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease]
```

Also no need to call

```
pair = [pair init];
array = [array init];
```

Try removing that. No need to do the init (Initializer) whenever you are assigning it with an object.

Comment: Thanks--I'm beginning to get a handle on properties but allocating/initializing them still confuses me.  This helps.